# Looping throw links using PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

There is a problem. I have some urls. And there are a list of links on this urls, which I want to visit. Each of this links. There is no problem with looping throw urls, but problems with this links. Here is my code...

```
var urls = [];

var TEMPLATE = 'https://example.com/page/'

for (var i = 1; i > 0; i--) {
    urls.push(TEMPLATE + i);
}

var page = require('webpage').create();
//Here is looping throw urls
function process(){
    if (urls.length == 0){
        phantom.exit();
    } else{
        url = urls.pop();
        page = require('webpage').create();
        page.open(url, onFinishedLoading);
    }
}

function onFinishedLoading(status){

    var links = page.evaluate(function() {
        var arr = [];
        //Here we are grab links inside urls
        $('some.selector').each(function() {
            arr.push( $('a', $(this)).attr("href"))
        });

        return arr;

    });
    //And this is just my tries to visit this links
    link = links.pop();
    //Just fine. Get the link
    console.log(link);
    parse(link);

    setTimeout(function parse(link) {
        page.open(link, function(status) {
            var parsing = page.evaluate(function() {
                return link + status;
            });
            //Don't work :(
            console.log(parsing);
        });
    }, 1500);

    page.release();
    process();

    // return links;

}

process();
```

Sorry for my silly question, i little know at phatom and JS.
Wish you can help me

Comment: Can you post the output of console.log(parsing) ?

Comment: It is like this "https://example.com/link", wich i get with console.log(link). And then it gets freeze. I wait about 15 minutes, and there is now changes. So I think there are problems, when I try to visit this links